# Socket-Handling in a Local Proxy Server

Tags: c#, http, sockets, proxy

he when writing a local proxy server, I need one Socket, that communicates with the Browser (BS) and one Socket that communicates with the Webserver (WS). I've already tried to implement a Proxy. It works, but it is horrible slow. I guess, the reason for this is, that I create a new WS for every Request that arrives from Browser. Therefore a new connection to WebServer is created with every Request. I guess I should use one WS and one Connection for every Request Proxy must forward to the same IP. Is this right?

Comment: Have you profiled it to see where it is slow? I would *expect* that to be more related to the IO code. Not respecting keep-alive for connection re-use would make it a *bit* slower, but not "horrible slow".

Comment: No I didn't do this yet. I will take a closer look at the code. To state this again: I'm using a new Connection for every Request. For every Picture, HTML-File, CSS-File, Javascript... and so on. I've read that W3C recommends to only use two connections from a single client to a webserver.